# Nested case expression and indentation error

Tags: haskell

I want to use nested `case-expressions` so i tried to write this code and i am stucked here from last 2 hours and can't figure out why is it giving me error on the last line.

```
getAdjacency :: [Node a] -> Map.Map k v -> Map.Map k v
getAdjacency matched adjacency = matched >>= (\(x,y,d) -> do
   case (Map.lookup y adjacency) of
                   Nothing -> Map.insert y (x,d) adjacency
                   Just ((nod,value)) ->
                                      case ((d + distance) < value) of
                                        True -> (Map.insert y (x,d+distance) adjacency)
                                        False -> (Map.insert y (nod,value) adjacency)
```

It says `parse error(Possible indentation error or mismatched brackets)`

What is wrong in the last line?

Comment: Why do you use a `do`?

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis to match the one just before your lambda expression.

Comment: Using `Map.findWithDefault` instead of `Map.lookup` would let you eliminate one of the `case` expressions.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i  just started learning haskell and yes i changed this function to `foldr` instead of using `>>=` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close the `(` to the left of `\(x,y,d)`. Decent editors will highlight the bracket that corresponds to the bracket at your cursor, or color brackets in pairs, which helps to debug the mismatched bracket error.

Consider using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:alter for your use case.